# if statement with tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

[image]

I used Mr. Medina's very helpful code (below) but when the example runs from one page to another, there is a line at the bottom of the first page and one on top of the second page. Could someone please help me correct it? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}

\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south east) -- 
        ([xshift=3pt]box.east);
    \fi
  }
}


\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}}
  {\end{exa}\end{eoexample}}  


\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{example}

\clearpage

\begin{example}

\lipsum[1]

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`overlay` code is applied to non broken boxes but also to each fragment of a broken box. You can decide to which fragment is `overlay` code applied with options `overlay unbroken`, `overlay first`, `overlay last`, ... (Please look at 4.11 Overlays section in [tcolorbox](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}

\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay unbroken ={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  }
}

\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}}
  {\end{exa}\end{eoexample}}  

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{example}

\clearpage

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\clearpage

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image: 4 pages]

Comment: Thank you so much :) Also, to make the QED box always shows up on the right of the line, I tried to play around with East, West... in the code but it didn't quite work. Specifically, on page #2, I'd like to have the box on the right of the line. Can you give me some hint? Thank you.

Comment: And is there anyway to get rid of the gray lines around the border?

Comment: @SeanN I've updated the code and now, QED is always shows up on the right of the line. The gray lines around the border where a viewer artifact. Now the image has been taken from Adobe Reader and now lines are shown.

Comment: Thank you. You are so resourceful. I'm not sure if I should ask the following question in a different post. But I added the package marginnote to write text right below "You Try it" using this code:\begin{example}
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Simplify $i^{100}$.}}}[-.5cm]
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Answer: 1.}}}[-1.2cm]
\end{example}. Is there a way for me to include this in the existing code in the preamble so that I don't need to type the whole command every time? I tried it with \newcommand. But I'm hoping to include the block in the "YouTryIt" codes.

Comment: @SeanN I think that what you want it's not too dificult and I'll think about it. But It's better to ask it in a new question because it's not related with this one.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use your `overlay` code as `overlay unbroken`. Also add this code for when the `tcolorbox` is broken:

```
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south east) --
        ([xshift=3pt]box.east);
    \fi
  }
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}

\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay unbroken={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south east) --
        ([xshift=3pt]box.east);
    \fi
  },
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south east) --
        ([xshift=3pt]box.east);
    \fi
  }
}


\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}}
  {\end{exa}\end{eoexample}}


\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\lipsum[1]

\end{example}

\bigskip

\begin{example}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{example}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]